# Netbeans 7.2 and PHP on localhost

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, localhost, netbeans-7.2

I have been developing a PHP project solely in Dreamweaver. After determining that Netbeans will make my life easier, I installed Netbeans 7.2 for PHP.

I followed the project setup guide, yet I am having issues with the project folders. I can edit and save source files, but how do I update the files on the localhost?

Specifically, I have the project source files located on our work drive, which I can use as a regular hard drive. I even have a site file for this project in Dreamweaver, with the source folder, the local folder, and the remote folder profiles all set up and functioning well.

Do I need to change how I store the project files? My Netbeans project properties are as follows:

```
Sources
-Project Folder: D:\work\cms\current
-Sourec Folder:  D:\work\cms\current
-Test Folder:

Run Configuration
-Configuration: <default>
-Run As: Local Web Site (running on local web server)
-Project URL: http://localhost/cms/current/
-Index File: index.php
```

And I see no other relevant settings, but if you ask about any I will update my question.

When I make a change, I save and select Run. The page loads as expected, but the changes are not there, the localhost copy did not get updated. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `Copy files from Sources Folder to another location` checked in the Project Properties > Sources category?

Comment: No. The instructions said not to check that if I already have files in the "other location".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install an FTP server e.g filezilla server and in the project "run configuration" change to remote web server, then specify localhost and the ftp details.

Or create a script to copy over the project e.g .bat or .sh depending on OS.

Or change your project location to be inside the localhost web directory and just use it in there.

I had the same issue, I gave in and now have apache pointing to my project folders on my development machine.

Comment: I tried the FTP idea, it sounded great, but I couldn't get Netbeans to connect to my localhost. I ended up going with how you did it, and have the sources as the directory that Apache points to. Thanks!